# Post array data in c#

Tags: c#, web-services

I am trying to post an array data to server and it's working, but the problem is data mixed with header part.

```
        string url = "http://localhost/test.php";
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        string Page = "";
        NameValueCollection collection = new NameValueCollection();
        collection.Add("pid", "1");
        collection.Add("specialist", "1");
        collection.Add("examiner", "1");
        byte[] responseBytes = webClient.UploadValues(url, "POST", collection);
        string responsefromserver = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
        Console.WriteLine(responsefromserver);
        MessageBox.Show(responsefromserver);

        webClient.Dispose();
```

Comment: Can you please explain "*data mixed with header part*"? Taking the time to write a good question will go a long way toward getting you a good answer quickly.

Comment: how do you know `data mixed with header part`? do you use a tool like fiddler or something to observe the request header? show the header.

Comment: i got data in a single array.  but i want pid, examiner etc in single array and other data in separate array?

Comment: Please show (relevant parts of) contents of `responsefromserver`

Comment: {"pid":"1","bca":" { , { ","sampleId":"28,28","testId":"LDH,LDH"}

Comment: I actually want is as {"pid":"1","bca":"{" { "sampleId":"28"}", "{"testId":"LDH"}"}"}

Comment: Please add these two **nicely formatted** to your question.

Comment: i have like this var a = new int[][] { new[]{ 1, 1, 1, 1 }, new[]{ 2, 2, 2, 2 } };  Now how to post this.